# Find the sum of first elements of a two-dimensional integer array

Tags: java

There is an integer two-dimensional array:

```
int[][] arr = {{3, 4},{5, 6, 7},{10, -4, 7}};
```

I want to find the sum of first elements: `int sum = 3+5+10;`

I can write:

```
int sum = 0;
for (final int[] i : arr)
    sum += i[0];
```

But I want to find the sum without using a traditional *for* loop.

I’ve tried reduce:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).reduce(0, (a, b) -> a[0] + b[0])
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What's wrong with a `for` loop?

Comment: What issue you are getting while trying reduce ?

Comment: @RyanZhang This question is of no practical use, just a theoretical question.

Comment: @DeepakPatankar identity value can't be int because a & b are int[]

Comment: you passed `0`  as initial value for `a`. since `0[0]` is not a valid expression,  it wont work.

Comment: Re *"But it is not working."*: What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).reduce(0, (a, b) -> a[0] + b[0])
```

The reduce mapper takes a two-dimensional array and expect to return an array, but you return an int.

So another way to solve it is by this:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).mapToInt(a -> a[0]).sum()
```

First I mapped the int Array to int (first element of the array), and then I used the sum for that stream.

You can check this free tutorial from Oracle for stream API:
https://dev.java/learn/the-stream-api/

Comment: The link is broken: *"404 Duke Lost"*. Was it just blindly copied from somewhere without even checking if it worked or not? Or did it work at the time?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = {{3, 4},{5, 6, 7},{10, -4, 7}};
        
        int x = Arrays.stream(arr).map(vec -> vec[0]).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
        
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

> stream(arr) : takes array of arrays and returns a stream of arrays of arrays.

> .map(vec -> vec[0]) : takes the lambda between parenthesis and executes it for every element in the stream, mapping the result in an output stream (it is an adapter). In this specific lambda we take the array and output the first element.

> .reduce(0, Integer::sum) : it's the final consumer of the stream (also known as collectors). Takes a collector function (in this case the sum) so that all elements in the stream are collected in a summing variable starting from value 0 (the first parameter).

Comment: For people who know map/reduce this solution is probably obvious, can you please add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: `reduce(0, Integer::sum) ` = `reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b)` ?

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what did you change and *why*? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73267704/edit), not here in comments (***** ***** ***without*** ***** ***** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in the comment, passing `0` as initial value for `a` is not a valid since `0[0]` is not valid, and therefore your code is wrong.
You can do something like this:

`Arrays.stream(arr).reduce(new int[] {0}, (a, b) -> new int[]{a[0] + b[0] })[0];`

Which reduces the two-dimensional array into a one-dimensional array with one element that represents the sum and then prints its first element.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since there are subarrays of different sizes. It's worth to make sure that an element at index `0` exists, meaning that array isn't empty. Otherwise you might get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Secondly, you don't need to use `reduce` here.

In the Stream API, we have several specialized forms of reduction. An action of obtaining the total **sum** of elements of a *primitive stream* is represented as a `sum()` operation (sure, it's possible to use `reduce()` for that, but it makes your code unnecessarily verbose and less expressive).

Also, note that you might encounter *integer overflow* while adding the first element of each subarray together. To avoid that, if you have no clear constraints regarding the input, it makes sense to resort to `LongStream`.

```
int[][] arr = {{3, 4},{5, 6, 7},{10, -4, 7}};

long sum = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .filter(a -> a.length > 0)
    .mapToLong(a -> a[0])
    .sum();
```